# The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed in scrollview and sliding drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

Im getting this error in my activity on line 7 by I have no idea why please help.
i want to add sliding drawer in bottom so i can drag it up to show other content 
like when i show some team info , i want to drag players from sliding drawer to top

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/archivecontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/football_grass_text" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/archivecontainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/showsinglearchive_imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/showsinglearchive_textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/showsinglearchive_imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_table" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/showsinglearchive_textview2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView><SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@id/handle"
        android:layout_width="88dip"
        android:layout_height="44dip"
        android:background="@drawable/ballbg"
        android:text="help" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/football_grass_text" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/archivecontainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</SlidingDrawer>
```

Comment: Please explain why would you post xml file if you have a bug in the Activity?

Comment: layout i mean @R.id.pandacoder

Comment: Can i see your logcat error? (Full please) Add to post.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you closed your main parent scrollview layout where you started your sliding drawer. This is your first mistake. 
Second , if there is an error in your activity, you should post your activity code